# bug in my code memory manipulation

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am not sure if I can post here these types of questions, please let me know what you think and I can delete the post if necessary.

I am experimenting with some C style code but I am having trouble finding my bugg. Can anyone see the mistake?

Note: I know there's few memory leaks ( i will fix later)

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

size_t returnSize(const char* s)
{
       string string(s);
       return string.size();
};

size_t returnSize(const int& i)
{
       return sizeof(i);
};

size_t returnSize(const char& c)
{
    return sizeof(char);   
};

template<typename T>
string Serialize(const T& t)
{
    T* pt = new T(t);
    char CasttoChar[returnSize(t)];
    for (int i =0 ;i<returnSize(t);i++)
    {
        CasttoChar[i] = (reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pt)[i]);
    }

    char* pX = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (returnSize(t) + 1));

    // I save size in byte 0 
    pX[0] = (char)returnSize(t);

    //I save value in subsequent bytes.
    for (int i = 1 ; i<=returnSize(t) ; i++)
    { 
        pX[i] = CasttoChar[i];                         
    }

    string returnString(pX);
    free(pX);

    return returnString;     
};
template<typename T>
T DeSerialize(const string& s)
{
     const char * cstr = s.c_str();

     int sizeofData = (int)cstr[0];

    char* cp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeofData);
    for (int i =0 ;i<sizeofData;i++)
    { 
        cp[i] = cstr[i];                          
    }

    T* result= reinterpret_cast<T*>(cp);

    return *result;

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = 10;
    string s = Serialize(x);
    cout << DeSerialize<int>(s);
  /*    
    I need to see: 
    10 as output
    now I see 4
  */    
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So basically I serialize number 10 and when I deserialize it I get 4.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: You say that you have a bug, but haven't explained what the bug is.

Comment: Ah I agree totally, Unfortuantely I am working on a PC that is very very old and installing a debugger is not working for me.

Comment: The bug is that instead of seeing 10 I see 4 in output

Comment: Well, at the very least explain what the symptoms are...

Comment: Nope, this ain't http://find-my-bug.com!

Comment: Ok So the idea is to be able to Serialize any basic type, then from a string retrieve back the information.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying the wrong bytes:

```
for (int i =0 ;i<sizeofData;i++)
{ 
    cp[i] = cstr[i];                          
}
```

Since cstr[0] is the length, it should be:

```
for (int i =0 ;i<sizeofData;i++)
{ 
    cp[i] = cstr[i+1];                          
}
```

[Also, you need to make SURE that your strings never exceed the size of 128!]

Oh, and further: Passing a `char*` into a `std::string` assumes that your string is a C-style string. So if you have a zero-byte in your string, it won't work. May be better to have a data-structure that is just a length and a dynamically allocated char-array.

I also believe you will copy the wrong bytes from a `std::string` type, since you are simply casting the address of the string to a char *, and that's the "object std::string", not the actual string content - you need "c_str()" for that.

Answer (score 0):

One source of bug:

```
string s = Serialize(x);
```

should be

```
string s = Serialize<int>(x);
```

Comment: Eh? Why? The compiler should be able to sort that out.